# ServiceStack DTO Assembly

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, servicestack

We are building our first small implementation of ServiceStack and we need some clarification regarding DTO's located in a separate assembly that is shared between the client and the server.

[The WIKI page for the new API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API) recommends the following for DTO

> *In Service development your services DTOs provides your technology agnostic Service Layer which you want to keep clean and as 'dependency-free' as possible for maximum accessibility and potential re-use. Our recommendation is to keep your service DTOs in a separate largely dep-free assembly.*

There is also this snippet

> *But let's say you take the normal route of copying the DTOs (in either source of binary form) so you have something like this on the client:

```
[Route("/reqstars")]
public class AllReqstars : IReturn<List<Reqstar>> { }

The code on the client now just becomes:

var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);
List<Reqstar> response = client.Get(new AllReqstars());
```

> *Which makes a GET web request to the /reqstars route. When a custom route is not present on the client it automatically falls back to using ServiceStack's pre-defined routes.*

My question is... does the "largely dep-free" assembly still require a dependency on ServiceStack due the the route attribute on the DTO classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[Route]` attribute exists in the [ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/RouteAttribute.cs) project, so you still only need a reference to the dependency and impl-free **ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll**. This is by design, we want to ensure the minimum dependency as possible which is why we'll try to keep all metadata attributes you might use on DTO's in the Interfaces project.

The reason for wanting to keep your DTO's in a separate assembly is to reduce the dependencies required by your clients in order to use it. This makes it less invasive and more accessible for clients. Also your DTOs represent your Service Contract, keeping them separate encourages the good practice of decoupling them from the implementation, which you want to continue to be free to re-factor.

Comment: Thank you mythz. I am all in favor of keeping the DTO's in a separate assembly, I just wasn't sure if there was a method to make that assembly zero-dep.

Comment: @mythz I'm in awe of ServiceStack and a little overwhelmed by the amount of info (many contradictory). This answer helped me on the right track to create a ServiceModel dll with my DTOs but I didn't find anything on ServiceStack's doc pointing it that way. There's nowhere there that states that the only needed reference is ServiceStack.Interfaces. The RESTIntro ServiceModel's include references to LOTs of DLLs, so it is confusing too. Is there a nuget package to get only this bare-minimum reference to build a ServiceModel?

Comment: @Loudenvier ServiceStack.Interfaces is in the ServiceStack.Common NuGet package, there's nothing more finegrained on NuGet at the moment (there will be after the big NuGet re-factor). In practice this isn't an issue since `ServiceStack.Common` is the min package required for clients to be able to use [ServiceStack's typed .NET Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client). In general, you should strive to keep your service models dep-free, minimizing deps/friction required by clients.

Comment: @mythz Finegrained Nuget for ServiceStack's components is need of the hour looks like as I'm having to add `ServiceStack.Common` to my repository layer as well apart from DTO component.

Comment: I really don't understand this design, why the route is in the RequestDTO and not in the service declaration/methods?

Comment: @riadh the Route is not an implementation detail, it's a metadata extension to the explicit public Service Contract which is why it's on the Request DTO's that is also shared with and leveraged by clients.

Comment: @mythz i understand that, for me a DTO does not have to be aware or annoted with the route that he will be used. but perhaps you have a good reason for that.